# How to convert a single component of REACT JS project to NEXT JS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a multi component React JS project in that I want to do server side rendering for one of the components and want to use Next JS for that. But I am not sure if it is possible to convert only single component to Next JS without converting the whole project..

Can anyone help me to know how can we achieve this

Thanks In Advance

I am not sure about the steps to convert only single component to Next JS without converting the whole project..

Expecting steps that I can follow to convert single component to Next JS

Comment: I don't think that is possible but perhaps I'm wrong. Because with NextJS your server will render the HTML before sending it to the client. But when you have a React project the code is send to the client and rendered there.

So if you have a React project that handles rendering on the client it's it cannot be rendered on the server anymore.

Comment: I found below on a blog, just wanna know the steps to achieve this. 

"Converting a React js app to Next js is not that complicated. The convenience is you don't have to convert every single component in your React app. For example, you can convert the blog post page of your blog to Next js and continue using React js on the contact us page."